# PHP include class not working

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to use a php class plugin on my project. (Windows)

https://github.com/mhor/php-mediainfo

It is a very basic question but I don't know how to make this work.

My code:

```
<?php
    include '/mediainfo/MediaInfo.php';
    $mediaInfo = new MediaInfo();
```

And I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MediaInfo' not found in index.php on line 15
```

/mediainfo/MediaInfo.php:

```
<?php

namespace Mhor\MediaInfo;

use Mhor\MediaInfo\Builder\MediaInfoCommandBuilder;
use Mhor\MediaInfo\Container\MediaInfoContainer;
use Mhor\MediaInfo\Parser\MediaInfoOutputParser;

class MediaInfo
{
    /**
     * @param $filePath
     * @return MediaInfoContainer
     */
    public function getInfo($filePath)
    {
        $mediaInfoCommandBuilder = new MediaInfoCommandBuilder();
        $output = $mediaInfoCommandBuilder->buildMediaInfoCommandRunner($filePath)->run();

        $mediaInfoOutputParser = new MediaInfoOutputParser();
        $mediaInfoOutputParser->parse($output);

        return $mediaInfoOutputParser->getMediaInfoContainer();
    }
}
```

I don't know about 'Mhor\MediaInfo\'. I just downloaded the source from Github and  and extracted it to the root www /mediainfo:

- /
- /index.php
- /mediainfo/... (all files and folders)

I tried some other class and get the same error.

---

after trying Tanmay Kumar' suggestion:

```
$mediaInfo =  new \Mhor\MediaInfo\MediaInfo();
```

the error is fixed, but the next line:

```
$mediaInfoContainer = $mediaInfo->getInfo('video.mp4');
```

gives:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mhor\MediaInfo\Builder\MediaInfoCommandBuilder' not found
```

Comment: try include 'mediainfo/MediaInfo.php';

Comment: Just tried it. Same error.

Comment: You need to add the namespace ...oops hit enter too soon `use Mhor\MediaInfo;`

Comment: Some light reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete correct method:

```
include '/mediainfo/MediaInfo.php';
use \Mhor\MediaInfo\MediaInfo;//now you can directly call class on it's name

$mediaInfo = new MediaInfo();
```

Let me know if you face anymore problems :)

Comment: Change it to `use \Mhor\MediaInfo;`

Comment: Sorry boss, I misread the statement it should be changed from to `use \Mhor\MediaInfo\MediaInfo;` from `use \Mhor\MediaInfo;` And this will work.

Comment: Almost there. Now : `Fatal error: Class 'Mhor\MediaInfo\Builder\MediaInfoCommandBuilder' not found`

Comment: Okay under the above statement write this as well: `use Mhor\MediaInfo\Builder\MediaInfoCommandBuilder;`. If the error still persists include that class as well before the statement using this `include '/MediaInfo/Builder/MediaInfoCommandBuilder.php';`

Comment: Staying here until your problem is resolved, when it's done let me know so I can write the complete answer above so it may help someone else in future as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77835/discussion-between-azevedo-and-imran).

Comment: The guy went went with more better and stable solution i.e. http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ It was recommended in chat to him.

Answer (score 1):

replace $mediaInfo with:-

```
$mediaInfo = new \Mhor\MediaInfo\MediaInfo();
```

Comment: it solved partly. now i get `Fatal error: Class 'Mhor\MediaInfo\Builder\MediaInfoCommandBuilder' not found ` when trying: `$mediaInfoContainer = $mediaInfo->getInfo('file.mp4');`

Comment: still: `Fatal error: Class 'Mhor\MediaInfo\Builder\MediaInfoCommandBuilder' not found in`